# Stop automatic redirection in firefox

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to configure Firefox to manual page redirections?

In pre-30x versions of Firefox, and in other browsers back to era of usable Opera there was a switch which forced browser to ask user whether he wants to be redirected and to what page will redirection happen.

I see the setting in `about:config` named `network.http.redirection-limit`, but it's a guard for redirection loops, setting it to 0 makes Firefox spew an uninformative error on very first redirection.

Checkbox in "Advanced > General" just doesn't work at all. I want to stop **all** redirections, not only those caused by scripts (I suppose this checkbox does work only in cases `window.location` is changed by current page).

Is there a way?

Comment: Not quite sure if I understood it correctly, but you can configure redirection with addons as Redirect Remover or NoRedirect. Have you tried those? If not you can use those to add different patterns or block specific websites to redirect. Are you trying to say, that you want to block all redirection but also get a message where the page was redirected?

Comment: @ErlisD. What I was trying to say is that for years in all browsers I had used I had a switch which allowed me to force browser to **not** automatically redirect me, asking each time for manual confirmation. This mode was apparently removed from later versions of Firefox, which is horrible disgrace of its developers. That's what I am "trying to say".

Comment: @ErlisD. Redirect remover is not what I am wanted, it seems to work only for specific URLs, rewriting them. I mean true 302 redirects.

Comment: I understand... You are right, it's really a shame they removed it. But if you can configure NoRedirect properly you get almost what you want. 
For example, add this pattern: `^https?://(?:[^/]+\.)?(?:.+)\(?:.+)` , select source and dns error, and try if it works. P.S. Try a page you haven't opened before, or clear you browser history for this to work. For me it blocked 301/302 redirects.

Comment: @ErlisD. I added NoRedirect rule as you said, opened Google, entered arbitrary search query, and clicked on first search result. Firefox redirected without any questions.

Comment: Strange... I tried it and worked, and after retrying it, it doesn't work anymore. Most probably the addon is buggy. It was last updated in 2011.
If you really want this option, try to ask also on mozilla support.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/new/desktop/privacy-and-security